# How to make my marker overlay clickable

Tags: javascript, wordpress, google-maps-api-3, jquery-gmap3

I am trying to build a site based on Elegant Themes "[Explorable](http://www.elegantthemes.com/gallery/explorable/)" WP Theme, which is in turn based on gmap3 jQuery plugin. It makes WP Posts shown of the map as markers. These markers have overlays, that tell post names and categories, but are not clickable. I am trying to make them linked to actual post pages. Yet something is wrong.

Below is the code with my added part. When I uncomment the part I added, the maps is not loading at all. Please tell me, what I am doing wrong.

```
function et_add_marker(marker_order, marker_lat, marker_lng, marker_description) {
    var marker_id = 'et_marker_' + marker_order;

    $et_main_map.gmap3({
        marker: {
            id: marker_id,
            latLng: [marker_lat, marker_lng],
            options: {
                icon: "<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/blue-marker.png"
            },
            events: {
                click: function (marker) {
                    if (et_active_marker) {
                        et_active_marker.setAnimation(null);
                        et_active_marker.setIcon('<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/blue-marker.png');
                    }
                    et_active_marker = marker;

                    <!--marker.setAnimation( google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);-->
                    marker.setIcon('<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/red-marker.png');

                    $(this).gmap3("get").panTo(marker.position);

                    $.fn.et_simple_slider.external_move_to(marker_order);
                },
                mouseover: function (marker) {
                    $('#' + marker_id).css({
                        'display': 'block',
                        'opacity': 0
                    }).stop(true, true).animate({
                        bottom: '15px',
                        opacity: 1
                    }, 500);
                },
                mouseout: function (marker) {
                    $('#' + marker_id).stop(true, true).animate({
                        bottom: '50px',
                        opacity: 0
                    }, 500, function () {
                        $(this).css({
                            'display': 'none'
                        });
                    });
                }
            }
        },
        overlay: {
            latLng: [marker_lat, marker_lng],
            options: {
                content: marker_description,
                offset: {
                    y: -42,
                    x: -122
                }
            }
            /* This is my code, that doesn't work */
            events: {
                click: function (marker) {
                    window.location.href = "<?php 'the_permalink' ?>";
                }
            } /*End of my code*/
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: there is a comma missing between options and events

Comment: Oh. You were right. So simple, I'm ashamed. Too bad to be a noob :-) Thank you! 
BTW, "the_permalink" was missing brackets after, but this I fixed myself.

Comment: Oh, I should have asked you to promote your comment to an answer so that I could accept it and raise your reputation :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a comma missing between options and event. Thanx to Dr.Molle.